# How can I mount an ISO Image in Windows 7 WinPE?

Tags: disk-image, windows-pe

I have a 16GB USB flash drive that I want to set up like this:

- It boots WinPE
- It has useful diagnostic and system maintenance tools
- There are several .ISO files of operating system install DVDs on the flash drive
- I can mount one of the .ISO files and start an OS install.

Perhaps there's a way I can use Virtual CloneDrive within WinPE?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk). I've used this to install Windows 7 from a USB disk where Windows wouldn't install if it did not see its files on a DVD. I used the steps [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?prev=hp&hl=en&js=y&u=http%3A%2F%2Fbbs.wuyou.com%2Fviewthread.php%3Ftid%3D148722%26extra%3Dpage%253D1&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&history_state0=) to install the driver from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is install the OS you could use `Diskpart` to partition the drive, `ImageX` to copy a custom .wim file to the partition and `BCDboot` to copy boot information to the system partition.

Check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349348%28WS.10%29.aspx) out for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use ***GRUB4DOS*** to do things like this.  It's a boot loader capable of booting from ISO images, floppy images or partitions located on any media (USB, CDROM/DVDROM etc.).  I personally have a USB stick with WinPE/ImageX, a huge collection of diagnostics and install media for Win7 and a few linux distros.